# Knockout difficult

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I was trying to make an example using `Knockout.js` which is not working. I created a function that creates the object

```
var makeproduto = function (id, nome, preco, quantidade) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Nome = ko.observable(nome);
    this.Preco = ko.observable(preco);
    this.Quantidade = ko.observable(quantidade);

    this.ValorTotal = ko.computed(function () { 
        return this.Quantidade() * this.Preco();
    }, this);

    return this;
};
```

And another function that populates an entity of products

```
var productListTemp = function () {
    this.produtos = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(1, 'Pão', 045, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(2, 'leite', 135, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(3, 'ovos', 035, 96));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(4, 'guarana', 425, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(5, 'fanta', 425, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(6, 'coca cola', 500, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(7, 'torta pedaço', 215, 60));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(8, 'torta inteira', 990, 10));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(9, 'sorvete - frutale', 225, 100));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(10, 'sorvete - magnum white / black', 500, 50));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(11, 'sorvete - magnum gold', 600, 25));
    this.produtos.push(produto.makeproduto(12, 'bolo de cenora', 995, 100));
    return this.produtos();
};
```

And then the `DataBind` not working on any of the data on the screen.

```
MountList = function () {
    var temp = productListTemp();
    this.vm = ko.observableArray(temp),
    this.quant == ko.computed(function () {
        return this.vm().length;
    }, this);
},

DatabindFunction = function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new MountList());
};
```

Where can I be wrong?

Comment: From where do you call `DatabindFunction `? How does your view look like?

Comment: I called the DatabindFunction inside of my route javascript class...

When I call the firts link...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `new` keyword for creating objects in `productListTemp` function:

```
this.produtos.push(new produto.makeproduto(1, 'Pão', 045, 100));
```

When you just call function `this` pointer has another context - `window` and you add all properties to it instead of new object.

Comment: In addition remove `return this` from constructor function

Comment: If you want to use constructor `makeproduto` without `new` you should add the code `if (!(this instanceof makeproduto)) return new makeproduto(id, nome, preco, quantidade);` as the first line of function `makeproduto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var makeproduto = function (id, nome, preco, quantidade) {
        this.Id = ko.observable(id);
        this.Nome = ko.observable(nome);
        this.Preco = ko.observable(preco);
        this.Quantidade = ko.observable(quantidade);

        this.ValorTotal = ko.computed(function () { 
            return this.Quantidade() * this.Preco();
        }, this);
    }
        , productListTemp = function () {
        this.produtos = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.produtos.push(new makeproduto(1, 'Pão', 045, 100));
        this.produtos.push(new makeproduto(2, 'leite', 135, 100));

        return this.produtos();
    };
```

Also you might consider ko.mapping plugin which creates objects with observable properties from plain JSON.

Comment: I found my error is inside the Route Class ... I tried to mount the html template using sammy.js "this. $ element (). append (" most did not work, when I added the html code directly on the page worked perfectly.

Can someone help me with this.

how could I load an external template using the knockout sammy +

Comment: You just need to use plugin and configure it right. It has nothing to do with sammy.

Comment: Also consider watching John Papa course on SPA you can find it easily. It covers your questions as well as those you'll have after =)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get rid of the extra '='

```
this.quant = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.vm().length;
        }, this);
```

You could also use Pure Computed in Knockout 3.2.0 and above
It will provide performance and memory benefits

```
this.quant = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return this.vm().length;
        }, this);
```